# Jquery .load() cross origin del mismo subdominio

Tags: jquery

Tengo un problema a la hora de actualizar el contenido de una sección cuando intento hacerlo con `.load()` de jQuery.

No sé por qué, pero intenta cargar el contenido del dominio principal en vez del subdominio en el que estoy.

El error que recibo es:

> **XMLHttpRequest** cannot load https://www.miweb.com/master/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://prueba.miweb.com' is therefore not allowed access.

La linea que utilizo es:

```
$('.refresh').load('contact.php?id=' + contactId + ' .refresh');
```

Comment: creo que estas haciendo uso incorrecto de las comillas pruebalo así: .load("contact.php?id='" + contactId + "' .refresh");

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Me comí la primera comilla pero solo aquí en la descripción porque luego en el código la tengo bien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta agregar este tag a tu `<head>`:

```
<base href="prueba.miweb.com">
```

Con ese tag, debería buscar todos los archivos partiendo de esa base.

Answer (score 5):

Tu problema viene dado por que "https://www.miweb.com/master/" tiene un subdominio diferente a "https://prueba.miweb.com" aun que el dominio sea el mismo el subdomino 'prueba' es diferente a 'www', si quieres que funcione debes agregar las cabeceras CORS a tu archivo contact.php.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
```

Por desgracia esto le da accesso a cualquier dominio

Otra solución sería

```
$http_origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
if ($http_origin == "https://www.miweb.com" || $http_origin == "http://www.domain2.com" || $http_origin == "https://prueba.miweb.com")
{  
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin");
}
```

Por último podrías modificar tu archivo .htaccess si usas apache. Para que quede algo como esto.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(prueba.miweb.com|www.miweb.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

EDIT: O simplemente puedes meter todo bajo el mismo dominio www.miprueba.com y te evitas configurar cabeceras.

Comment: Hola Alejando. Gracias por tu respuesta bien explicada. Creo que sé como funcionan los CORS lo que no entiendo es porque hace la llamada a www.miweb.com cuando yo trabajo sobre prueba.miweb.com. Intenté poner la ruta completa del subdominio de la siguiente manera $('.refresh').load('https://prueba.miweb.com/contact.php?id=' + contactId + ' .refresh'); pero tampoco me funciona.¿Estoy haciendo algo mal ?

Comment: Ok, entendí mal, ya probaste con lo siguiente?$('.refresh').load(location.host + '/contact.php?id='; + contactId + ' .refresh') si aun así no funciona, verifica que sea el propio host el que no te este haciendo una re dirección.

Comment: Me has salvado. Muchas gracias. Tenía un 301 :P